# nvidia kernel module version mismatch

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, dkms

Yesterday I run `apt-get dist-upgrade` on my kubuntu 19.10 and after reboot there is no nvidia kernel module for the loaded kernel version.

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.0.0-17-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-015) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1)) #18-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 4 15:34:08 UTC 2019

# dkms status
nvidia, 440.59, 5.3.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed

# modprobe nvidia
modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.0.0-17-generic
```

I try to

- deinstall `apt purge nvidia-driver-440` and install `apt install nvidia-driver-440` the nvidia drivers
- install `nvidia-kernel-source-440` and repeat the previous step
- install dkms again

but nothing changed the situation. What can I do now? Why there is a version mismatch between kernel and the nvidia module and how to solve this?

Comment: How it happened that the 5.3.0-59-generic was installed?

Comment: I do not know that. But if I could correct this, the problem would be solved. (I hope)

Comment: Reinstall nvidia drivers.